# Powershell-replace portion of string for multiple files

Tags: mysql, regex, powershell, replace, parentheses

I have a folder with multiple sql files (think 1,000+ files). What I need to do is loop through all the files within the folder and replace a certain portion.

Each file has contents like so:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
  column1 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  column2 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  column4 DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  column5 DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  column6 VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  column7 TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column8 VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  column9 INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  column10 TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
ENGINE = INNODB,
AUTO_INCREMENT = 5,
AVG_ROW_LENGTH = 4096,
CHARACTER SET latin1,
COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci,
COMMENT = 'generic table comment.';
```

My goal here is to loop through the entire folder for each of these files, detect where `(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)` is present, and change it to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (without the parentheses). The problem I'm encountering is I cannot seem to do a simple replace for the parentheses only, because it would remove them from other columns such as varchar or int datatypes as well as the primary key and create table statement as a whole.

What I had in mind is something similar to

```
$GetFiles = Select-String -Path "C:\Users\name\NewProject1\Tables\*.sql" -Pattern "(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)"
foreach ($File in $GetFiles){
$NewContent = Get-Content $File.Path | ForEach-Object {
$_ -replace "(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)","CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"
}
$NewContent | Set-Content $File.Path
}
```

But this does not appear to be working, and keeps the parentheses around CURRENT_TIMESTAMP. Any thoughts or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `-replace` is a regex operator, you need to escape parentheses: `-replace "\(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP\)"`

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something stupidly simple I was missing. Your answer worked like a charm. I'm unable to mark your response as the answer but it is indeed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `-replace` operator defaults to *regular expressions*, which is why you need to escape `(` and `)` with `\`, either manually:

```
... -replace '\(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP\)','CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'
```

... or with [`Regex.Escape()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape?view=net-5.0):

```
$pattern = [regex]::Escape('(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)')
... -replace $pattern, ...
```